# How to spawn object thats spawn objects

Tags: particles, procedural

How to create some kind of program in blender that spawn object capable of spawning other objects?

Only thing i need is spawning random object from some collection, and the object which is spawned automatically spawn random object from other collection.

I need it to happen in normal scene because i want that creation to export.

I tried it by particles system but blender 2.8 can't spawn particles that spawns particles.

Comment: I can't give you a proper answer, because I lack knowledge in this area, but you should look for the Particle Instance modifier.

Comment: Can you add more detail about the effect that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok i added more details